# Set date as artifactory directory name in jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, groovy, artifactory, jenkins-groovy

I have a DSL script that creates a pipeline to push to jfrog artifactory. I want to create a target directory in artifactory with current date as directory name.

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
env.buildDateString="\${new SimpleDateFormat('yyMMdd').format(new Date())}-\${env.BUILD_NUMBER}"

...
...

//artifactory step
{
 "pattern": "*abc*.zip",
 "target": "myrepo/application/\${env.buildDateString}\\n/artifacts/"
}
```

The above script is giving the below snippet

```
 {
  "pattern": "*abc*.zip",
  "target": "myrepo/application/${env.buildDateString}\n/artifacts/"
 }
```

I want the directory to be created using the date. How to refer the buildDateString in "target" section of artifactory so I get output like this

```
"target": "myrepo/application/220328/artifacts/"
```

Answer (score 0):

Why the slashes?
backslash () is used to escape special characters in every type, except dollar-slashy string, where we must use dollar ($) to escape.

In your case just do as below,

`env.buildDateString="${new SimpleDateFormat('yyMMdd').format(new Date())}-${env.BUILD_NUMBER}"`

```
{
 "pattern": "*abc*.zip",
 "target": "myrepo/application/${env.buildDateString}/artifacts/"
}
```

sample
[image]

Comment: I am getting the following error when I remove backslash script: 80: unable to resolve class SimpleDateFormat 
 @ line 80, column 13.
   Build_ID="${new SimpleDateFormat('yyMMdd').format(new Date())}-${env.BUILD_NUMBER}"
               ^

Comment: Check your classpath once and also update the details on the error in your query.